# scroll text left and right Based on scroll by GSAP in angular

Tags: angular, gsap

Need to **scroll text left and right** Based on scroll by **GSAP** in angular.Am new to GSAP so can you please help me to clear the solution .
sample is in the below link
https://velas.com/#hero

I did some research and came to an solution but in that when i scroll down the text scrolling is proper but when i scroll up the text scroll is not proper.can you please help me in that.
below is my code for reference:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-trigger-yubdla?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: What's "not proper" about it? It's doing what you're telling it to do...

Comment: ya bro i got the solution.I waited for the response in stackoverflow no response so i did from myside and got the solution.Thanks for the response bro.

Comment: @ZachSaucier can u please tell how to make smooth movement for text like the below site https://velas.com/#hero